# How can I use mathematical symbols and other special characters in URLs in footnotes?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, footnotes, urls

I want to footnote a URL which contains mathematical signs such as `=` and LaTeX asks me for a `$` sign to take it to mathematical space (and therefore changing the font which is not suitable). How should I overcome this situation, i.e. put url in footnotes without using a $ sign and evading mathematical space?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Please indicate whether you're loading package such as `url` and/or `hyperref` that provide a macro called `\url`.

Answer (score 12):

The most straightforward and flexible approach to typesetting URL strings is to use the `\url` macro that's provided by the [url](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/url) and [hyperref](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) packages. I use the word "flexible" in part because `\url{...}` can usually find good line breaks -- an important consideration when dealing with long URL strings (which occur quite frequently, right?). Outside of footnotes, just about any and all of TeX's "special characters" (including `%`) can feature in a URL string that's encased by `\url{...}`.

However, due to some fairly deep-seated restrictions on what can be typeset by LaTeX in a footnote, you'll find that you *cannot* use `\url` *inside footnotes* if the URL string contains the `%` (comment) character.

You have two options if the URL string does contain one or more `%` characters:

- Load the [fancyvrb](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) package, execute `\VerbatimFootnotes` after `\begin{document}`, and typeset the URL stringin the footnote using the `\Verb` (note the uppercase **V**) macro.

  Upside: pretty much all characters are allowed. Downsides: automatic line breaking of long URL strings not possible, and URL string won't be made into a hyperlink if the `hyperref` package is loaded.
- Use the `\urldef` directive (also provided by the `url` package) *outside* the footnote to define a "robust" macro that contains the URL string, and then use this robust macro inside the footnote itself.

  Upsides: can use just about all characters, and preserve ability to break lines automatically. Downside: must remember to use `\urldef` before getting to the footnote.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{url,fancyvrb}
\setlength\textheight{3cm} % just for this example
\begin{document}
\VerbatimFootnotes % enable use of \Verb in footnotes

%% specify a URL string that contains '%' characters
\urldef{\myurl}\url{http://!@#$^&*%_=+<>%}

Some text.\footnote{Using \Verb+\url+: \url{http://!@#$^&*_=+<>}.}

More text.\footnote{Using \Verb+\Verb+: \Verb|http://!@#$^&*%_=+<>%|.}

Yet more text.\footnote{Using \Verb+\urldef+: \myurl.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 I would stick to `\urldef`, it's the clear and consistent way IMHO.

Comment: @tohecz - The advantages of `\urldef` would certainly seem to outweigh its disadvantage of having to remember to use it *before* entering the footnote material.

Answer (score 0):

As Trefex pointed out, you can use the special symbols by escaping them with `\`.  Nevertheless, a most elegant solution would be to load the [`url`](http://www.ctan.org/url) package.

Once you have called it in your preamble (`\usepackage{url}`) you should be able to use urls anywhere with any special characters (_, $, #, etc.)

Comment: A limitation of using `\url` is that you can't have URL strings containing `%` (comment) characters if they need to be typeset in footnotes -- as is the case with the OP's issue. Two workarounds: `\Verb` (from the `fancyvrb` package), or pre-define a "robust" macro that contains the URL string using `\urldef` *before* entering the footnote zone.

Comment: Really? Thanks for the head's up :)  I'll exclude `%` from the answer