# Writing long email address in a footnote

Tags: titles

I am writing a `twocolumn` document. But the problem is the author's email is split in to two lines with a hyphen. How can I remove the hyphen from the email?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Something}
\author{Author\thanks{department name, institute name with details- abcdefghijklmnopqr@xyz.com}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}

\maketitle
\lipsum[2-5]
\end{document}
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Use `\protect\url{abc@rest.com}` provided by package `url`.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/180183/5001 and, in particular, the use of `\urldef` to typeset URL-like strings (such as email addresses) in footnotes.

Comment: @Johannes_B - Your proposed method works as long as the email address doesn't contain `%` characters.

Comment: @Mico: `%` characters in a mail address?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - There's nothing inherently illegal about `%` characters occurring in email addresses.

Comment: @Mico: Ok, I never saw a mail address with `%` characters, so I just wondered. Thanks for keeping me up-to-date ;-)

Comment: @Mico Wasn't aware of that. But `url` provides a solution for this as well: `\urldef{\personalMail}\url{abcd%fg@provider.com}
\author{Author\thanks{\protect\personalMail}}
`

Comment: @Mico I missed your comment on `urldef` above. The question now seems to be a dupe.